# Image not appending in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript, I am trying to append a img tag inside a div tag.
but it is not concatinating with already existing elements inside the div.

This is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="ce_label">
       <span>some text</span>
       <span>some text</span>
    </div>
```

My javascript Code :

```
    var sel = '.ce_label';
    var toolTemplate = [
    '<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">'
    ];
  window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
  var commentHtml = toolTemplate.join('');
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].appendChild = commentHtml;
  }

  };
```

So my output should be :

```
 <div class="ce_label">
        <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">

       <span>some text</span>
       <span>some text</span>
    </div>
```

But I could not get this output..

Can anyone help me to fix it???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output do you get, if any?

Comment: `appendChild` adds the element to the end of the chain. If you want the img to be added as the first child then go for `insertBefore` method. [example here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_insertbefore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
x[i].appendChild = commentHtml;
```

tries to assign a string to the element's `appendChild` property, which refers to a function you can't overwrite.

If you want to replace the element's content with that HTML, assign to [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```
x[i].innerHTML = commentHtml;
```

If you want to append to the element's curent contents, call the element's [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method:

```
x[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", commentHtml);
```

Comment: Great It Works. I just worked it like jQuery Append() function. Now I understood clearly. Thanks @T.J. Crowder.